# Flutter rounds DateTime value to 3 decimal places

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart, datetime-parsing

I'm developing a web app using Flutter front-end and FastApi. I encountered this issue while using `DateTime`, that its value has a different length in either of the languages (Python & Dart).

**DateTime object from python**

```
2022-01-25T13:09:03.914910
```

**DateTime object parsed from response**

```
2022-01-25 13:09:03.915
```

I observed that Dart rounds the DateTime value to 3 decimal places.

How to get around this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using the default `toString()` on the `DateTime` object. What you might need is the `toIso8601String()` method. Here's a code sample to show the difference.

```
final now = DateTime.now();
print(now); // 2022-01-25 11:04:08.053
print(now.toIso8601String()); // 2022-01-25T11:04:08.053
```

Comment: I'm not using `toString()`. I'm just using the Datetime object and getting same output as yours, but it's not the desired output.

Comment: Dart has less precision on its DateTime objects (3 decimals) than Python (6 decimals) I think. In most cases this shouldn't be an issue, but it can depend on your use case. If you need that exact precision, maybe DateTime isn't the object you'd like to use and manual handling would be more fitting for your use case

Comment: @ASADHAMEED Of course you're using `toString()`.  `2022-01-25 13:09:03.915` is a `String`.  How did you get it?  If you used `print` or used string interpolation, that implicitly calls `toString()` for you.

Comment: @dumazy Sort of.  Dart `DateTime` objects have a field for microseconds, but Dart *for the web* (e.g. DartPad) will not preserve them due to JavaScript limitations.